# how to listen a cell of gridview if its value changed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a gridview and I pass It records from db and I want to change a column value when click It and save the new value into db namely update the grid how can I achieve that.Is it possible to listen a cell of gridview if its value changed or not?

Comment: You are using gridview populating from database. Are you using datagrid to change value or what?

Comment: How are you taking input from user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the CellValueChanged or CellEndEdit events or you can even try the below :

```
private void grid_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // do something with grid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a saveButton and in it's click event you can save edited data to database:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow[] modifiedRows = (gridView.DataSource as DataTable).Select("", "", DataViewRowState.ModifiedCurrent);
    foreach (DataRow row in modifiedRows)
    { . . .}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into CellValueChanged event which gets triggered when cell value is changed in a DataGridView. Note that this event gets triggered when the cell loses focus.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged(v=vs.110).aspx)